# How do I put vectors on the same list in R?

Tags: r, list, concatenation

Basically I have a list of the form

data<-c("1,2,3,4","5,6,7,8")

I want to convert everything to numeric

so that the output is:

[1] 1 2 3 4

[2] 5 6 7 8

how do I do so?

Comment: `strsplit(data, ",")` gives me a two-element list, each element being a `character` vector length 4 (in this example). If you need them to be converted to numeric, then use `lapply(strsplit(data, ","), as.numeric)`.

Comment: It's unclear how `data` is really structured in R, since the "code" in your question is not correct R syntax. Further, your second code suggests it is part of a frame or matrix. Please provide sample data using `dput(x)` where `x` is just enough data to clearly show what you have. (The use of `dput` is unambiguous and will greatly facilitate direct answers.)

Comment: It would really help if your input data and desired output format were stated in working R syntax (e.g. show input as in my answer and output as `list(1:4, 5:8)`

Comment: Sorry, Im a newbie here. I was using (1,2,3,4) as it is used for example in python. The problem is: I have the variable "data" where data[i,] is of the form "1,2,3,4". Basically, I was converting "1,2,3,4" to 1 2 3 4, line by line. But I dont know how to put it together

Answer (score 1):

This is a little unclear, but if you have this object:

```r
d <- c("1,2,3,4","5,6,7,8")
```

then

```r
d |> stringr::str_split(",") |> unlist() |> as.numeric()
```

will convert it to a numeric *vector*. If you really want it as a list then appending `|> as.list()` will do the trick.

If you want the result to be a list of two numeric vectors then

```r
d |> stringr::str_split(",") |> purrr::map(as.numeric)
```

will work.

Comment: I tried your pieace of code above, but I wanted to have a list where the first line is (1,2,3,4)= list[1] and then list[2]=(5,6,7,8). Or in other words how do I put V1=(1,2,3,4),V2=(5,6,7,8),...,Vn=(....)  as newlist=(V1,V2,...,Vn) so that newlist[n]=Vn

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, but maybe something like this:

```
d <- c("1,2,3,4","5,6,7,8")
d <- as.list(d)

as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(d[[1]], ",")))
```

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
```